# Accessing SSDT data for programmatic manipulation

Tags: sql-server, bids, kendo-ui, sql-server-data-tools

I have an MSSQL 2012 Reporting server set up, and many, many reports made in Sequel Server Data Tools. I would like to have access to the data returned in those reports through C#/ASP.NET.

The end result is to display the data in the KendoUI DataViz suite, but first I need to convert the reports into JSON on the server side.

Is this possible?

**Edit:** To be clear, I need to know how to access the report data from the web server. Converting data into JSON format is not what I need assistance with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked the question, I've learned I can use the atom feed button on the reports to download a .atom file, which contains a URL that provides report data in XML.

You'll need to replace the & in the URL with '&', and then you have a working URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I suggest you to take a look how to return [JSON](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/how-to-return-json-data-from-mvc-controller/) with ASP.NET MVC and how it works.

Comment: I'm well aware of how to use JSON/ASP.NET/etc - the data I'm looking for is not on the web server however. It is on the reporting server. I need to access the Reports from the web server, this is the piece I've been struggling with. Rereading the question, that might not have been clear. I'll update it.